# Ordering JOIN results when grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by, left-join

Take the below for example:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    auctions AS a 
    LEFT JOIN winners AS w ON a.auction_id=w.auction_id
WHERE 
    a.active=1 
AND 
    a.approved=1 
GROUP BY
    a.auction_id
ORDER BY
    a.start_time DESC
LIMIT
    0, 10;
```

Sometimes this may match multiple results in the `winners` table; I don't need both of them, however I want to have control over which row I get if there are multiple matches. How can I do an `ORDER BY` on the winners table so that I can make sure the row I want is the first one?

Comment: Please don't do this. When you select `*` with a `GROUP BY` on a single column, your order will never be guaranteed.

Comment: Can you post your table structures?

Comment: What is `GROUP BY a.auction_id` supposed to do in your query? You're not aggregating, and you're also selecting more columns than the `GROUP BY` clause. (I've never understood why mySQL allows this)

Comment: Can you please post some sample data explaining how it should be ordered? Also are you looking for just ordering or you want to get the only row that has the latest start_time?

Comment: @njk I knew someone was going to comment on that haha.... that is just for the purpose of an example as I had too many columns & I didn't really need to display them here. :)

Comment: @lc. This is code from some software that I have been customizing, so I didn't put the `GROUP BY` there myself; a function basically builds the query from a lot of criteria & perhaps there is a bug in there where `GROUP BY` shouldn't be included in this instance!? I haven't really analyzed the code that far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   auctions AS a
       LEFT JOIN (select auction_id from winners order BY auction_id limit 1) AS w ON a.auction_id = w.auction_id
WHERE  a.active = 1
       AND a.approved = 1
GROUP  BY a.auction_id
ORDER  BY a.start_time DESC
```

Change the reference to the winners table in the join clause to a sub-query. This then gives you control over the number of records returned, and in what order.

Comment: @Brett if you want the first date for each auction, then this answer will not return that.  This returns only one record in the subquery, it does not return one record for each auction.

Comment: `SELECT TOP`? What is `TOP`? This question is tagged with "MySQL", not "SQL-Server" ..

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to accurately answer without seeing your table structure but if your `winners` table has a winner date column or something similar, then you can use an aggregate function to get the first record.

Then you can return the record with that earliest date similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM auctions AS a 
LEFT JOIN winners w1
  ON a.auction_id=w1.auction_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  select auction_id, min(winner_date) MinDate -- replace this with the date column in winners
  from winners 
  group by auction_id
) AS w2
  ON a.auction_id=w2.auction_id
  and w1.winner_date = w2.MinDate
WHERE a.active=1 
  AND a.approved=1 
ORDER BY a.start_time DESC
```